# Insert column of data from excel into emacs dat file

Tags: excel, database, emacs, format

I'd like to copy and paste a column of numbers from an excel spreadsheet to make another column in a data file.

That is, in my .dat file I have data like

```
x1  y1  z1
x2  y2  z2
x3  y3  z3
..  ..  ..
```

and so on. I'd like to copy and paste a column of numbers `ei` from my excel spreadsheet to make another column in this dat file such that I get

```
x1  y1  z1  e1
x2  y2  z2  e2
x3  y3  z3  e3
..  ..  ..  ..
```

Is there an easy way to do this? The existing rectangles emacs functions, as far as I can see, only allow you to generate columns with a single number input by user and not file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Paste the column from excel into a different/temporary buffer<sup>1</sup>, and then use the rectangle commands to copy/kill that as a rectangle and yank it into the .dat file buffer.

---

<sup>1</sup> or you could even do the initial paste it at the end of the .dat buffer, if that was more convenient.